# What information about a magic item is not revealed by Identify?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

The spell *[identify](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/identify)* provides the following effect when used on an object:

> If it is a magic item or some other magic-imbued object, you learn its properties and how to use them, whether it requires attunement to use, and how many charges it has, if any.

That seems like most of the information about any magic item. One specific exception is:

> **Cursed Items:**
>   Some magic items bear curses that bedevil their users, sometimes long after a user has stopped using an item. A magic item's description specifies whether the item is cursed. 
>   **Most methods of identifying items, including the *identify* spell, fail to reveal such a curse, although lore might hint at it.** (DMG p 138-139)

So - given that restriction, and any RAW others, what is the sum total of information about an arbitrary magic item that would **not** be revealed by *identify*?

My specific use case is understanding when Identify can be limited within the rules (since limiting it arbitrarily is frustrating to players).

Subcategories may include:

- Specific magic items or general categories of magic items that call out restrictions on *identify*
- Magic item traits that call out restrictions on *identify*, like the example of Curses above
- Spells or effects independent from the magic item being identified (i.e. a spell that has been cast on it, its surroundings, or the caster of *identify*) that would prevent information about that item from being revealed by *identify*

Comment: While the answer *might* be small, the question itself is too broad. The answer to your title is essentially "everything that explicitly states *Identify* won't reveal this thing", but it seems you want the list of everything that says it. Is it right?

Comment: Yep that's correct. I can see it might be too broad, but my specific use case is understanding when Identify can be limited within the rules (since limiting it arbitrarily is frustrating to players).

Comment: You may want to ask that directly instead of asking this different question and hoping it answers your real question. (Since there are no answers here yet you could just [edit] this post; if you do, don’t forget to update the title, too.)

Comment: Vigil I have edited in your comment to clearly declare your use case.  Per @SevenSidedDie 's point, please edit/trim the question so that this core problem stands out. (Let's give this a chance to be reopened as not too broad).